# Windows 10 Not able to discover on network using IPV4 / IP address

Tags: windows-10, ping, ip-address

I am facing issue to ping or make TCP connection to my Windows 10 system. I am able to ping other systems. From other systems I am not able to ping to my IP address. When try to ping with my Computer name, it pinging but giving response from IP6 address. Please help on this.

IP address start with 192.168

When i ping using computer name getting the response. But its showing ip6 address only.
I tried this,

**ping computername -6** (getting response).

**ping computername -4** (no response)

Enabled ICMP. Even
Turned off the firewall also. But still issue. No Antivirus running on my PC.

Thank you

Check IPconfig /all

[My PC - has issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/447AU.png)

[The PC I am trying to ping to my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DfVk.png)

in the PC has issue. Have IP Routing Enabled. How to disable that.

Comment: what happens when you try ping computername -4 ? is ICMP enabled for IPv4 in your windows firewall?

Comment: When i ping using computer name getting the response. But its showing ip6 address only. I used this too also  ping computername -6 (getting response). ping computername -4 (no response)

Comment: on the "computer name" machine follow these steps https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/allow-pings-icmp-echo-request-through-your-windows-vista-firewall/

Comment: yes enabled ICMP

Comment: Whats the ip address of your PC and the one your trying to ping?

Comment: both are same IP address only

Comment: Please post the output of `ipconfig /all` from both machines to your question

Comment: Please check the image attached on my thread for ipconfig /all

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling VPN resolved the issue.

Finally its my office VPN installed to take remote desktop.

Comment: @zx485: What answer?   While it is threadbare (what does it mean?  did the OP *fix* the problem, or just understand its cause?  if they fixed it, how?), this *is* the answer.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that you were the questioner. Otherwise this would classify as a "Thank you" comment. But in this case, it does mark the question as solved.